# How can I get the length of a list in Rules?

Tags: rules

If there is another way to check if a list is empty, that is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom module eg. customrules and create customrules.rules.inc in this module.
In customrules.rules.inc place following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function customrules_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'customrules_list_length' => array(
      'label' => t('Get length of list'),
      'group' => t('Data'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'list' => array(
          'type' => 'unknown',
          'label' => t('List'),
        ),
      ),
      'provides' => array(
        'list_length' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('List length'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * The action for 'customrules_list_length'
 */
function customrules_list_length($list) {
  return array(
    'list_length' => is_array($list) ? count($list) : NULL,
  );
}
```

Now you should be able to use this action to get the list length

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Someone should post that to d.o though.

Comment: You can change the 'type' under the second 'provides' to other types (I'm using integer) if that is required.

Answer (score 1):

1. You might be able to doing without any coding using a view to just return the count of your list and if you have different lists you might want to use the views argument (D6) or the contextual filters (D7) to only use one view for all of them.
2. Using [Rules and Views Integration](http://drupal.org/project/rules_views) if D6 or [Views Rules](http://drupal.org/project/views_rules) if D7 you will be able to access the view from rules.